# Deleting new index after/during reindex operation

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, reindex

I'm new to Elasticsearch operations. I had to do a job of renaming the field names in an existing Elasticsearch index.

I updated the existing `ingest pipeline` by resubmitting the `ingest pipeline` configuration with additional `rename` processor.
I did not update the `index template` because the new `pipeline` name is still same.
Then I posted the request for re-indexing without prior creating the new index.
I noticed that the new `index` have got created on the `master node`.

I did not add any new `alias` name for the new `index` yet as I was thinking to see if the operation completes fine then I'll add those to reflect in my `kibana` search.
Also, I had not specified any field type and I see one of the date field was getting the string data and while conversion of field name, errors started coming in `elasticsearch` logs.

Now, I see the data for the index is not coming in the `kibana` search at all and there are error message in the logs

```
[o.e.x.i.IndexLifecycleRunner] [leader-node-02] policy [logs-for-dev-policy] for index new-index-v0] on an error step due to a transitive error, moving back to the failed step [check-rollover-ready] for execution. retry attempt [2]
```

I'm thinking to delete the newly created index `new-index-v0` as the old index `index-for-dev` is still there.
I tried reading the documentation but could not find a clue to know if deleting the new index will create any problem to the older index .
Any suggestions please ?

I am using Elasticsearch version 7.2 .

Comment: It seems that your old index was managed by ILM (hint: `IndexLifecycleRunner`) and your new index created some havoc in there. Can you confirm?

Comment: @Vai, Thanks for responding 
Yes, there was an index life cycle management policy 
New index does not have any ilm or anything defined, it was just used on the fly 
in the `reindex` command as a destination value

Comment: Are you sure that there's no index template matching the new index name (`new-index-v0`) and having `index.lifecycle.name` in the settings? That's what the error seems to hint at

Comment: Also it seems the parsing/reindexing operation did not complete normall as I see there was an error . "failed to parse field [api_version] of type [date] in document with id". 
Even though I have not specified any data type for the apiVersion/api_version field.

Comment: I see, the default template pattern is getting applied to this new index too because the name is similar and template is applied for "name-*"

Comment: Yes, that's probably the reason

Comment: Now, I'm just wondering if deleting this new index will cause any data loss to me ?
Any other options which I can use to avoid data loss ?

Comment: Why a data loss? the two indexes are identical right?

Comment: I deleted the new index finally, there were errors in conversion of one field and also the alias were not set to the field. 
I see, there is no data available for the time this new index was there .. after deleting the new data has started coming into old index